# What is the name of this pawn structure for black, with doubled c and f pawns?

Tags: pawn-structure

Is there any name for this pawn structure?

[image]

Comment: Probably "awful"

Comment: I hereby dub it the "Cubicle" structure, since there are flimsy walls on 3 sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Chess Fundamentals," former World Champion J.R. Capablanca would refer to Black's knight pawns as being "doubled toward the center."

Answer (score 4):

There is no special name for the structure you show where black has doubled c and f pawns.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty terrible pawn structure so I doubt it has a specific name. Actually, most pawn structures don't have a name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific name for this pawn structure, there are just certain "elements" that it has. You have the doubled c and f pawns (arguably weak, but it depends on if they become blockaded or not), as well as the strong pawn center. Black's a and h pawns will become weaker as the game goes on and it is doubtful that they can utilize the half open g and b files to create any real kind of pressure.